# Clang format newline for each parameter when char over character limit

Tags: clang-format

What parameters in clang format allow this transformation?

```
test(arg1, arg2,  arg3, arg4);
```

should be

```
void test(
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3,
  arg4);
```

So far I have tried

```
  ColumnLimit:80
   AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
   binPackParameters = false
   and binPackArguments = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong syntax. The correct entries in .clang-format would look like this:

```
ColumnLimit:80
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
BinPackParameters: false
BinPackArguments: false
```